# Adding an event listener to a div to perform an event if the div becomes empty (has no children)

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

My goal is the following: create a listener that will be bound to a div and it will fire up if there are no children left in that div.

I keep seeing how to bind a listener to say `onClick` etc.. but I cannot seem to find anyone that deals with actual states of the elements (empty, at least one child, etc... ). I have not started coding anything yet because I am not sure what kind of approach I need to take, since I am pretty new to JavaScript development. I am not necessarily looking for an answer with code in it but more of an advise on what approach to take.

One of the approaches that I was thinking of was to simply have a function call every single time I make a change to the div such as deleting a child but that seems too trivial. I want to create some kind of automation in that process of checking for no children.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has `remove` event fired when element is removed

```
$(el).on("remove", function () {
    alert("Element was removed");
});
```

You could use `live` (if they are appended dynamically to parent container) or `on` (if statically) method to bind this event to child nodes of particular container and on every `remove` event check if parent container has any child nodes. If not then do some actions.

Comment: The thing is that the parent div may have hundreds of children... so I cannot actually bind the event handler to every child... I was looking for something where I bind a parent div and check if anything within it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a listener to a div element to check if the element has no children(done automatically without knowing which function is removing the children, but only knows that there was a child removed). Granted you could do a function to check every so many seconds but that is not what I wanted. Anyways, where I remove the children, I simply added a function that checks if the parent is left with no children and it handles it there.

Comment: Answered by  the OP in an edit. [Moved to this wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)